# Python Class Object Error

Tags: python, class, object, sprite, pong

I am trying to make a "crazy pong" game for a class. the requirements are to duplicate the ball after bouncing. This edition also requires that there be 3 types of balls one regular one that shrinks the paddle and the other the makes the paddle grow. My code so far is:

```
from livewires import games, color, random
import decimal


games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.black,
                                top = 460, right = games.screen.width - 10)
games.screen.add(score)

class Paddle(games.Sprite):
    """
    A paddle controlled by player to catch falling pizzas.
    """
    SMALL = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    LARGE = 3
    images = {SMALL  : games.load_image("paddle.bmp"),
              MEDIUM : games.load_image("paddlemid.bmp"),
              LARGE  : games.load_image("paddleBig.bmp") }

    def __init__(self, size):
        """ Initialize Paddle object. """
        super(Paddle, self).__init__(image = Paddle.images[size],
                                  y = games.mouse.y,
                                  bottom = games.screen.width)

        self.size = size

    def update(self):
        """ Move to mouse x position. """
        self.y = games.mouse.y

        if self.top < 0:
            self.top = 0

        if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
            self.bottom = games.screen.height

        self.check_catch()
        self.check_catch_grow()

    def check_catch(self):
        """ Check if ball bounces """

        for BouncingBall in self.overlapping_sprites:
            BouncingBall.handle_bounce()
    def check_catch_grow(self):
        """ Check if ball bounces """

        for GrowBall in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.destroy()

            new_paddle = Paddle(3)
            games.screen.add(new_paddle)
            GrowBall.handle_bounce()


    def check_catch_shrink(self):
        """ Check if ball bounces """

        for ShrinkBall in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.destroy()
            ShrinkBall.handle_bounce()

class BouncingBall(games.Sprite):
    """
    A ball that bounces around the screen and duplicates on paddle bounce.
    """ 
    image = games.load_image("bouncingBall.bmp")
    speed = 1

    def __init__(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        """ Initialize a ball object. """
        super(BouncingBall, self).__init__(image = BouncingBall.image,
                                    x = x, y = y,dx = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(50,300))/100 , dy = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(1, 3)))

    def update(self):
        """ Check if bottom edge has reached screen bottom. """
##        if self.right > games.screen.height or self.left < 0:
##            self.dx = -self.dx

        if self.bottom > games.screen.height or self.top < 0:
            self.dy = -self.dy

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.left < 0:
            self.destroy()
            self.end_game()

    def handle_bounce(self):
        global score

        self.destroy()
        new_ball = BouncingBall(x = self.x + 1, y = self.y, dx = -self.dx, dy = self.dy)
        dup_ball = BouncingBall(x = self.x + 1, y = self.y, dx = random.randrange(1,3), dy = random.randrange(1,3))
        score.value += 10
        score.right = games.screen.width - 10




        # self.dx = -self.dx
##        self.dy = -self.dy

        games.screen.add(new_ball)
        games.screen.add(dup_ball)

    def end_game(self):
        """ End the game. """

        end_message = games.Message(value = "Game Over",
                                    size = 90,
                                    color = color.red,
                                    x = games.screen.width/2,
                                    y = games.screen.height/2,
                                    lifetime = 5 * games.screen.fps,
                                    after_death = games.screen.quit)
        games.screen.add(end_message)

class ShrinkBall(games.Sprite):
    """
    A ball that bounces around the screen and duplicates on paddle bounce.
    Makes Paddle Small
    """ 
    image = games.load_image("shrinkBall.bmp")
    speed = 1

    def __init__(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        """ Initialize a ball object. """
        super(BouncingBall, self).__init__(image = BouncingBall.image,
                                    x = x, y = y,dx = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(50,300))/100 , dy = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(1, 3)))

    def update(self):
        """ Check if bottom edge has reached screen bottom. """
##        if self.right > games.screen.height or self.left < 0:
##            self.dx = -self.dx

        if self.bottom > games.screen.height or self.top < 0:
            self.dy = -self.dy

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.left < 0:
            self.destroy()
            self.end_game()

    def handle_bounce(self):
        global score
        new_paddle = Paddle(1)
        games.screen.add(new_paddle)
        self.destroy()
        new_ball = ShrinkBall(x = self.x + 1, y = self.y, dx = -self.dx, dy = self.dy)
        dup_ball = BouncingBall(x = self.x + 1, y = self.y, dx = random.randrange(1,3), dy = random.randrange(1,3))
        score.value += 10
        score.right = games.screen.width - 10




        # self.dx = -self.dx
##        self.dy = -self.dy

        games.screen.add(new_ball)
        games.screen.add(dup_ball)

    def end_game(self):
        """ End the game. """

        end_message = games.Message(value = "Game Over",
                                    size = 90,
                                    color = color.red,
                                    x = games.screen.width/2,
                                    y = games.screen.height/2,
                                    lifetime = 5 * games.screen.fps,
                                    after_death = games.screen.quit)
        games.screen.add(end_message)


class GrowBall(games.Sprite):
    """
    A ball that bounces around the screen and duplicates on paddle bounce.
    Makes paddle larger
    """ 
    image = games.load_image("growBall.bmp")
    speed = 1

    def __init__(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        """ Initialize a ball object. """
        super(GrowBall, self).__init__(image = GrowBall.image,
                                    x = x, y = y,dx = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(50,300))/100 , dy = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(1, 3)))

    def update(self):
        """ Check if bottom edge has reached screen bottom. """
##        if self.right > games.screen.height or self.left < 0:
##            self.dx = -self.dx

        if self.bottom > games.screen.height or self.top < 0:
            self.dy = -self.dy

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.left < 0:
            self.destroy()
            self.end_game()

    def handle_bounce(self):
        global score

        self.destroy()
        new_ball = GrowBall(x = self.x + 1, y = self.y, dx = -self.dx, dy = self.dy)
        dup_ball = BouncingBall(x = self.x + 1, y = self.y, dx = random.randrange(1,3), dy = random.randrange(1,3))
        score.value += 10
        score.right = games.screen.width - 10




        # self.dx = -self.dx
##        self.dy = -self.dy

        games.screen.add(new_ball)
        games.screen.add(dup_ball)

    def end_game(self):
        """ End the game. """

        end_message = games.Message(value = "Game Over",
                                    size = 90,
                                    color = color.red,
                                    x = games.screen.width/2,
                                    y = games.screen.height/2,
                                    lifetime = 5 * games.screen.fps,
                                    after_death = games.screen.quit)
        games.screen.add(end_message)

def main():
    wall_image = games.load_image("background.bmp", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = wall_image

    the_ball = GrowBall(x = 400, y = 200, dx = 1, dy = 1)
    games.screen.add(the_ball)

    the_paddle = Paddle(2)
    games.screen.add(the_paddle)

    games.mouse.is_visible = False

    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()

main()
```

I tried getting help within my class and have received no responses. I understand that my code is messy and I'm sure it carries quite a few redundancies. When I run the program I run into an error stating :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\crazypong 2.0.py", line 257, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\crazypong 2.0.py", line 255, in main
    games.screen.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 307, in mainloop
    object._tick()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 504, in _tick
    self.update()
  File "C:\crazypong 2.0.py", line 44, in update
    self.check_catch()
  File "C:\crazypong 2.0.py", line 51, in check_catch
    BouncingBall.handle_bounce()
AttributeError: 'Paddle' object has no attribute 'handle_bounce'
```

Comment: `self.overlapping_sprites` seems to have an object that doesn't have a `handle_bounce` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot locate the exact `livewires` module you are using, but it appears that `self.overlapping_sprites` *includes* the `Paddle` instance in the sprite list. You can ignore it by testing against `self`:

```
for BouncingBall in self.overlapping_sprites:
    if isinstance(BouncingBall, Paddle): continue
    BouncingBall.handle_bounce()
```

If that doesn't work then more than just the current paddle is listed in that list; you'd need to share the relevant `livewires` module code for me to determine that in more detail.

Comment: It didn't work and the code is too long for the question above.

Comment: Updated to filter *all* `Paddle` objects. I guess you are colliding with *another* paddle?

Comment: Progress has been made I just have to tweak a few things now but thank you very much for the help!